# Matrix monotone operators Intuition

Tags: matrices, optimization, operator-theory

can anyone explain by intuition that a matrix(operator) $A$ is monotone?
I know for normal functions if a matrix is monotone this means intuitively i can think of it as increasing, but hard to visualize/think about it when it is a matrix/operator form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about monotonicity in the sense of monotone operators, i.e. an operator $A: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is monotone if 
$$
\langle Ax - Ay , x-y \rangle \ge 0, \quad \forall x,y \in \mathcal{H}.
$$
Let $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a real matrix, then monotonicity is equivalent to 
$$
\langle Bx,x\rangle\ge 0,\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
This tells us geometrically that $B$ rotates every vector at most 90°. The one-dimensional equivalent is that non-negative numbers are mapped to non-negative ones and non-positive numbers are mapped to non-positive ones, i.e. the one-dimensional linear mapping has a non-negative slope.